# Pass data to Tab Bar Item (ViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

On photo below I show you my storyboard. On TableView Controller I have expandable menu. What I cannot achieve right now is to switch on second tab bar item (green one) and let it know what is ID of selected menu item. Between tab bar controller and green and blue controllers I have relationship "view controllers". I tried to call directly green view controller with this code:

```
let secondTab = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondstoryboardid") as! SecondVC

self.present(plavi, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code displays second tab view but without tab bar and everything derived from container view.

[image: My storyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configured correctly such storyboard, you should get the reference to the `UITabBarController` through `prepare(segue)`, doing so:

```
private weak var tabBarViewController:UITabBarController?

// be sure to add prepare inside your segue manager (the container in this case)
override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    self.tabBarViewController = segue.destination as? UITabBarController
}
```

besides you may want to declare an enum to have a clean access to the embedded view controllers:

```
enum TabType:Int {
    case blue
    case green
}
```

thus you might define a function for injecting the selected indexPath, doing something like:

```
func inject(indexPath:IndexPath, into tab:TabType) {
    if let greenVc = tabBarViewController?.viewControllers?[tab.rawValue] as? GreenViewController {
        greenVc.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        tabBarViewController?.selectedIndex = tab.rawValue // this will auto select the TabType viewcontroller
    }
}
```

finally whenever you have to change the current selection, you may call inject with the new indexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.inject(indexPath: indexPath, into: .green)
}
```

---

**Note**

Call `instantiateViewController` means making a new "fake" view controller, which is a wrong approach, since you already have it embedded in your `UITabBarController.viewControllers`

Comment: selectedIndexPath is not defined in GreenViewController and I defined it like 'var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath = []'. Everything else I changed according to your suggestion but there is some problem. Inside injection function I put breakpoints and concluded that I am never inside if conditional. That is reason why I still cannot switch to one of these ViewControllers connected to tab bar items.

Comment: what you mean for: "I am never inside if conditional", what is conditional? you mean this condition: `if let greenVc = self.tabBarViewController?.viewControllers?[tab.rawValue] as? GreenViewController` is failing?

Comment: Did you use the debugger to understand what is going on?

Comment: I tried also to fix it like this: if let greenVc = self.tabBarViewController?.viewControllers?[1] as? FirstViewController {... and put break point on this line but I cannot conclude what is wrong with this line. I am using swift 4 and xcode 9

Comment: I can share with you the whole project, I will upload it on google drive. Is it OK for you

Comment: Here is the code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NY3kiQHOZ9fVQyvEdztr9Z9gDY_8rcRY

Comment: Ok, I know why you fail there. I'll fix it for you.

Comment: zip version is here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NY3kiQHOZ9fVQyvEdztr9Z9gDY_8rcRY I do not know why it was not copied in previous link because I just dropped whole folder

Comment: OK then, thank you very much. Could you post it somehow here to help others too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163833/discussion-between-andrea-mugnaini-and-ognjen).

Comment: @Ognjen Ok, I added a comment about the main problem: where to add `prepare(for segue`