# Swift Pass data from a TabBarController to TableViewController

Tags: swift, swift3, segue

I'm lost in a maze with this theme.
I have implemented a Tab Bar Controller, that it is linked to 3 TableViewController with segues.
In the class of the Tab Bar Controller I have a series of variables, which I want to pass from the Tab Bar to each of the TableView. 
In summary, I do not know how to pass variables from Tab Bar to Table View with segues.

[image]

I tried this function in my TabBarController.swift:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let destinoController = segue.destination as? TableView1_Controller {

            destinoController.user = user
            destinoController.id = id
            destinoController.name = name

        }
    }
```

But it does not work at all.

I'm a little (pretty) lost

Comment: You are doing fine, you just need to create those variables in the corresponding TableViewControllers too. For example in the TableView1Controller, create a var user: User? or whatever you want

Comment: That's the problem. In the TableView1 I have create the vars. But they do not receive the parameters that happened to them from the tab bar :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to right below code, in click event where you are are tapping to move to next view controller and in sender you need to pass details and after that in your `prepareForSegue` method, you got details from sender

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your Identifier", sender: [AnyObject]())
```

Comment: But where should I add that code? In the tab bar it does not let me do click events. Sorry, I'm a little newbie with Swift

Answer (score 0):

If you connect the segues in the Storyboard, you can give them an identifier.

To do so you have to click on the segue and then check in the Attribute Inspector.

[image]

Now in your `prepareForSegue` method, you just have to check from which segue it's triggered :

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "yourSegueId" {
            if let destinationController = segue.destination as? TableView1Controller {
                destinoController.user = user
                destinoController.id = id
                destinoController.name = name
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Have a look at this answer : [Pass data tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413163/pass-data-to-tab-bar-item-viewcontroller)

Comment: It's good idea, but don't work because I can't give a name identification to a Relationship Segue (which is the type of segue used by the tab bar), only can do it in manual segue :(